# Uniform convergence of sequence

Tags: analysis, functions

Let $$f_{n}(t) = \frac{n^2t^2}{(1+t^2)^{n}}$$

I have to count limits

1. $$ \lim_{n \to +\infty}(\lim_{t \to 0} f_{n}(t))$$
2. $$ \lim_{t \to 0}(\lim_{n \to +\infty} f_{n}(t))$$
3. $$\lim_{n \to +\infty}f_{n}(\frac{1}{n})$$

My results: 1st and 2nd are equal to 0, 3rd is equal to 1.
My question, is this sequence uniformly convergnent for all real values of t?
I think it won't be because of this $\frac{1}{n}$ points, but how to write it formally?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may consider
$$
t \mapsto f_n(t):=\frac{n^2t^2}{(1+t^2)^{n}},\quad t \in \mathbb{R}.
$$ By differentiating $f_n$ one gets
$$
f'_n(t)=-2n^2t\:\frac{(n-1)t^2-1}{(1+t^2)^{n+1}}
$$ and, as $n \to \infty$, 
$$
\sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}}\left|f_n(t) \right|=f'_n\left(\pm \frac1{\sqrt{n-1}}\right)=\frac{(n-1)^{n-1}}{n^{n-2}} \sim \frac{n}e \to +\infty.
$$ The pointwise convergence is to $0$, thus the convergence can't be uniform on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But can we say that our sequence is not uniformly convergent without using differentation?